# Transverse submanifolds?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, transversality, submanifold

Let $M_1$ and $M_2$ be submanifolds of a manifold $M$. Assume that $M_1\cap M_2$ is also a submanifold of $M$ and that **dim**$(M_1)$+**dim**$(M_2)$-**dim**$(M_1\cap M_2)$=**dim**$(M) $. 
Is it true that $M_1$ and $M_2$ are transverse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, take $M = \Bbb R^2$, $M_1 = \{(x,y) : y = 0 \}$ and $M_2 = \{(x,y) : y = x^2\}$.